# I need some advide about user type with hashmap

Tags: java

I wrote user type as below

```
class Item {
   int first;
   int second;

   public boolean equals(Item p) {
       if(first == p.first && second == p.second ) 
           return true;
       else if(first == p.second && second == p.first)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
   }
   public int hashcode() {
       return Objects.hash(first, second);
   }
   public void set(Object first, Object second) {
       this.first = Integer.parseInt(first.toString());
       this.second = Integer.parseInt(second.toString());
   }
```

}

However, It doesn't work at all. Did I design the duplicate test incorrectly?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a meaningful problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include the details of *how* your program doesn't work.

Comment: Also, if by "duplicate test" you mean your `equals()` method, then yes, you've written it incorrectly.  For starters, there are tons of edge cases that you're ignoring, such as what is `p` if `null`?

Comment: Your `hashCode()` is not consistent with `equals()`. And it's also not named correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Some subtle issues:

- the signature of equals needs to be `public boolean equals(Object o)` (so, yes, you need to compare against Object, not your direct class)
- for hashcode, it should be `hashCode()`. And of corse, two objects that ewuals() deems equal need to have the same hashCode value. Which your implementation does not achieve.

The real lesson here: when you intend to **overwrite** methods, then put the @Override annotation above it, so that the compiler can tell you when you messed up big, or small.

In your case, you achieved to get both methods wrong that you *need* to get right when you intend to use your class with any of the java collection contains, such as Map/HashMap.